# How to bind NSTreeController's Children to Core Data ordered to-many-relationship?

Tags: cocoa, core-data, cocoa-bindings, nstreecontroller

Apple introduced ordered to-many-relationships in Core Data in Lion. I created an entity named TreeNode with an 1:1-object-relation, a 1:1-parent-relation and an ordered to-many-relationship children.

Then I have an `NSTreeController` with the children key path set to TreeNode.children. Running the application only shows first level elements. So children is not working. Since children is an ordered to-many-relationship, the corresponding class has an `NSOrderedSet` children. I added a custom method

```
- (NSArray *) childrenArray {
  return [children array];
}
```

to TreeNode which works. I could not find any documentation concerning that topic. Is it really the way to go when binding `NSTreeController` to an ordered to-many-relationship? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I haven't used ordered relationships like this yet but tree controllers have always been notoriously fussy. I would suggest getting it to work without the ordering first and then add the ordering.

Comment: I'm having the same issue as well. Is there any working example of NSTreeController working together with Ordered CoreData relationships?

Comment: Simply adding the childrenArray method solved the problem for me!

Answer (score 4):

It seems that Apple gave us ordered sets for Core Data but forgot to upgrade its binding controllers. One year later after your question, the problem is still there.

Have a look at:

https://github.com/robertjpayne/DDOutlineView

Moral of the story. Be careful when using ordered relationships, try to do your own implementation until Apple fully implements that feature

Comment: It seems this is still an issue.

Comment: Btw. i just opend a bug report for this ... may this helps :)

Comment: Github link is broken.  Proper link is here: https://github.com/neostoic/DDOutlineView