# NSOutlineView + NSTreeController + CoreData + Bindings Duplication of Rows

Tags: objective-c, core-data, binding, nsoutlineview

Firstly I'd like to mention that I've been using the [Apple Sample Code for the AbstractTree example](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/#samplecode/AbstractTree/Introduction/Intro.html).

I have the bindings working up to the point that they are displaying nodes and the two buttons that are set to `add:` and `remove:` are working too.

The problem I come across is when I'm dragging one of the nodes into another node to make it a child. You can see in the image below that I made **2a** and **2b** to drag under 2, which they *do*, but they don't delete from where I dragged them from. Furthermore if I delete either of them **both** are deleted.

[image]

I am using this [image]
 data model.

I have set the `TreeController` mode to Entity with it's name as Node (as in my model), which it's children key path to `children`. I have also bound it's MOM to the app delegate with a model key path of managed ObjectContext.

I have bound the value of the `Table Column` to the `TreeController`, its controller key `arrangedObjects` and its model key path as `name`.

I have uploaded the files here if you need them: [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20190820201944/https://s3.amazonaws.com/f.cl.ly/items/17132u2d2j451z1u3Z3m/UniOrganiser.zip?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJATDXY6T7PWOQPCQ&Expires=1566335983&Signature=%2BO8TwS2n6%2BtUd0TWp1%2B04vj0Z2c%3D&response-content-disposition=attachment)

Can someone help me? I'm a noob when it comes to CoreData!

Many thanks,
Gareth

Comment: The project you are linking to doesn’t look like your screenshot and the model you are describing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the fetch predicate of your `NSTreeController` to

```
parent == nil
```

and you can get this result. Thx for the test app :)

[image]

Comment: @GarethPrice you are welcome .. the answer to this questions may interest you too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7039165/  I expect the next thing will be the lost of the arbitrary ordering of your list because CoreData relationships are be default not ordered.