# NSBrowser not Repopulating children from NSTreeController after File Load via Core Data

Tags: cocoa, core-data, cocoa-bindings, nstreecontroller, nsbrowser

I have a Core Data based Document backed application making heavy use of cocoa-bindings.  I'm using an NSTreeController for populating an NSBrowser.  The main entity has a set of children, accessible via a relationship called "children".  I have no problem adding children and displaying them in the NSBrowser.  However, after I save a document and reopen it, only the main entities show in the browser, not their children.  I have verified by examining the file that the children are being saved along with a proper relationship (and inverse) to the main entities.  Has anyone else ever seen this?  Is there some obvious binding/setting that I'm probably missing?

Comment: The leaf and count keypaths aren't misleading when you're reopening?

Comment: I'm not using count and leaf is just a BOOL that is NO for the parent and YES for the children.

Comment: I didn't want to overcomplicate for the question but technically it's a 3 pane NSBrowser and the children have children too which are the actual leafs.  It goes Section->Question->Answer with the first two having leaf set to NO and Answer having it as Yes.  questions and answers are accessible via children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I neglected to mention that I'm using ordered relationships.  It seems this behavior (or lack of behavior) is related to bugs in Core Data's use of ordered sets in relationships.  I changed the relationships to not being ordered and they started loading correctly after being saved.  For more information see this question:
[How to bind NSTreeController's Children to Core Data ordered to-many-relationship?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7039165/how-to-bind-nstreecontrollers-children-to-core-data-ordered-to-many-relationshi)